# Android Camera Intent app doesn't return

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to show an image in an imageview with xamarin, but when I press the accept button in the camera it doesn't return to my main activity.

here is the code

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.AddPurchase);
    // Create your application here

    ConfigLayout ();
    if (IsThereAnAppToTakePictures ()) 
    {           
        CreateDirectoryForPictures ();
        Button cameraButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.buttonTakePicture);
        _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView);
        cameraButton.Click += TakeAPicture;
    }
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                var contentUri = Uri.FromFile (_file);
                mediaScanIntent.SetData (contentUri);
                SendBroadcast (mediaScanIntent);
                int height = _imageView.Height;
                int width = _imageView.Width;

                using (Bitmap bitmap = _file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height)) {
                    _imageView.SetImageBitmap (bitmap);
                }
}
bool IsThereAnAppToTakePictures ()
{
        Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        IList<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities (intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
        return availableActivities != null && availableActivities.Count > 0;
    }

void CreateDirectoryForPictures ()
    {
        _dir = new File (Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Boekhoudservice");
        if(!_dir.Exists ())
            _dir.Mkdirs();
    }

private void TakeAPicture(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_imageView.Drawable != null) {
            _imageView.SetImageResource (0);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

        _file = new Java.IO.File(_dir, String.Format ("uitgave_{0}.jpg", System.DateTime.Now.ToString ("d")));
        intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(_file));

        StartActivityForResult (intent, RequestCodeConstants.CameraIntent);

    }
```

It seems that the problem lies in my directory creation method, on the check if the directory exists it returns true while it doesn't show up in my file explorer if I go check for myself.

both these permissions are in my AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Could you add activity declaration from your Manifest.xml too?

Comment: As I'm doing this with Xamarin I don't have any activity declarations in my Manifest, all activities are registered with an `[Activity (Label="ActivityName")]` attribute above the classname